# I'm trying to connect to sql from load balanced instances

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to separate sql from my web app. I know I can connect an instance to sql by adding an ip or using proxy. The issue comes when I create a load balancer the will create different instances with different ip's. How can I make it dynamic in such a way that whenever an instance generated, automatically has access to sql?
My last resort will be opening sql to all ip's.
Also, is it reliable if I create a script on startup to start proxy in the background?

Comment: You answered your own question :) Use Cloud SQL proxy. It doesn't require IP whitelisting.

Comment: Right, but if I run it in the background I may also have to do a check on the process to see it is still working otherwise it would crash the instance which is why I asked if it is reliable. Have you done it? Did you have any problems with it?

Comment: Run it as a daemon (service) and let your system restart it if it crashes. The proxy is used by a lot of customers and it's pretty stable.